# Android Runtime.exec ("screencap") not doing anything (not working) and not giving any error

Tags: android, adb, runtime.exec

Running the command: `adb shell screencap /sdcard/image1.png` from the command line works, and the screenshot is taken and saved in the gallery as "image1.png"

But this doesn't work grammatically when doing:

```
String[] commandAndArgs = new String[]{ "screencap", "/sdcard/qweqwe.
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandAndArgs);
```

No errors or exception are thrown

Full code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{
        String[] commandAndArgs = new String[]{ "screencap", "/sdcard/qweqwe.png" };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandAndArgs);

        String error = "error: ";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            error += scanner.nextLine();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("err", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have permissions to run arbitrary stuff from within an app. Please use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+ if you want to take a screenshot from an app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check if exit code of the process is equal to zero, which indicates success.

```java
final int code = p.waitFor()
if (code != 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Code: " + code);
}
```

The other thing is that taking screenshots requires `android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER`, which is a signature permission only granted to system apps (including ADB shell). See, if you open a shell from your app it still runs with your app's permissions. And if your app doesn't have the permission it won't work.

Comment: Is there any way to prompt the user to give the app this permission ?

Comment: However, if asking for permission at the time of taking screenshot is fine, follow CommonsWare's comment and use Media Projection API instead.